# Improve speed of building a large sparse matrix in R

Tags: r, performance, indexing, nested-loops, linear-programming

I'm trying to build a set of constraints for a large-scale linear program that I plan to use in R with Gurobi. The code below creates a matrix with one of the constraints, but it runs extremely slow. I'm looking for ways to speed it up.

Right now, each of the i and j loops runs from 1 to 23, and the t loop runs from 1 to 192. The jnew loop also runs from 1 to 23. The a loop is only 1 currently, but I plan to increase that to 4 or 5 later on. The d[i,j] is a matrix of size 23x23. The MaxAirspeed is vector with one entry - again, I will increase that to 4 or 5 later on. The colfind function is directly below and involves just a couple arithmetic calculations.

```
colfind <- function(ii,jj,tt,aa,j,t,a) {
  x <- ii*(j*t*a)+jj*(t*a)+tt*(a)+aa
  return(x)
}
```

Here's the code that is causing me problems.

```
L <- 101568
time <- 192
ACNum <- 1
Airport <- 23

A <- simple_triplet_zero_matrix(nrow=time*Airport,ncol=2*L)
for (t in 1:time){
  print(t)
  for (j in 1:Airport){
    for (i in 1:Airport){
      timedist <- d[i,j]/MaxAirspeed[a]*4
      for (a in 1:ACNum){
        for (tau in 1:t){
          col <- colfind(i,j,tau,a,Airport,time,ACNum)
          A[(t-1)*Airport+j,col] = 1
        }
        for (jnew in 1:Airport){
          for (tau in 1:t+timedist){
            col <- colfind(j,jnew,tau,a,Airport,time,ACNum)
            A[(t-1)*Airport+j,col] = -1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help or suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what the expected output is? For a smaller example? It's difficult to reason through your code without running it and seeing what it does. Show us the output and it may be clearer what you want to do.

Comment: You are trying to populate a 4416x203136 matrix with nested loops in R. Prepare for glacial speed calculations. I'm having a difficult time understanding the indexing for A, but it seems that the calculations for A are independent so you can look into using `library(foreach)` to parallelize your loops.

Comment: It looks like you are using the `slam` package. Anything else we will need?

Comment: No. I think slam is the only package needed.